# why i am getting error when i write the "localhost:40000/music/?name=william" in chrome webbrowser

Tags: python, flask

when i write localhost:40000/?name=william it works.
so why is it not working for localhost:40000/music/?name=william

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/music",methods=['GET'])
def music():
    return "<h1>Hello, {0}</h1>".format(request.args.get('name'))

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello, {0}</h1>".format(request.args.get('name'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=40000,debug=True)
```

Comment: Please read the error, and paste it here if you don't understand it

Comment: here is the error on chrome "Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." but i expected "hello william

Comment: `/music/?name=william`, not `/music?name=william`? These aren't the same thing unless you have middleware doing normalization for you.

Comment: that's it @CharlesDuffy cheers. i'm kinda new and self learner. i saved a lot of time though i lost a lot to find the error. tysm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/music/` and `/music` are two different endpoints.

Your code handles requests for the latter; the URL you entered in your browser is for the former.